# Understanding the input of grid lstm.

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I was thinking about applying the grid-lstm on image. From its original paper, it is said that:

> Note that a block does not receive a separate data representation. A data point is projected into the network via a pair of input hidden and memory vectors along one of the sides of the grid.

As far as I understand, this means that unlike other variants of lstm, such as multi-dimensional lstm, whose input is a concatenation of *[all previous hidden vector, I*x], the grid lstm does not receive data point (say the RGB values) as input. Instead, those RGB features are directly used as the hidden/memory states of one side of grid-lstm. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding (and according to figure 2), the input data is directly fed into the hidden and memory vectors. Also, the output is derived from both, the outgoing memory and hidden vector. This suggests, that the original input can, if necessary, be passed through the whole depth-dimension (solving the vanishing gradient problem).

However, this does not affect the input projection (I * x), which I interpret as a preprocessing method (such as the word embeddings in the translation example 4.4). I believe, the notation of I * x was chosen to show the simplicity of the model. We still technically concatenate all incoming hidden vectors, same happens in the stacked/MD-LSTM.
RGB-points are still used as vectors, see in section 2.1:

> (...) the state of the network that comprises a hidden vector h ∈ R^d and a memory vector m ∈ R^d.

d, for RGB-images, would be 3. This is the definition of LSTMs that is later used, so we can assume the same thing holds for Grid-LSTMs.